# not able to pass vuex store data to graph

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuex, apex

Currently, I am trying to pass my data from vuex store into my apexcharts graph. However, it does not seem to work? Could anyone advise what I did wrong? I am mainly trying to update `this.series` and `this.chartOptions.labels` before the apexchart gets rendered.

cityPieChart.vue

```
<template>
  <apexchart type='pie' width='380' :options='generateChartOptions' :series='generateSeries'/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  created () {

  },
  computed: {
    generateChartOptions () {
      this.chartOptions.labels = this.$store.getters.cities.cities
      return this.chartOptions
    },
    generateSeries () {
      this.chartOptions.series = this.$store.getters.cities.cities_count
      return this.series
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    series: [],
    // series: [],
    chartOptions: {
      chart: {
        toolbar: {
          show: false
        }
      },
      labels: [],
      // labels: [],
      title: {
        text: 'Cities Analysis',
        align: 'left',
        floating: false
      },
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          options: {
            chart: {
              width: 200
            },
            legend: {
              position: 'bottom'
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  })
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In computed property `generateSeries()`, you are assigning getter to `this.chartOptions.series`, but returning `this.series` which is `undefined`.

`generateChartOptions()` might be OK, as I am not familiar with graph library, but you are assigning it to `this.chartOptions.labels` abd returning only `this.chartOptions`.